# Calling API in loop with combine and updating UI

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have downloaded a list of data from an api in following class:

```swift
public final class ExerciseListRemoteProvider: ExerciseListRemoteProviderProtocol {
    private let httpClient: HTTPClient
    private let url: URL
    
    public init(
        client httpClient: HTTPClient,
        url loadURL: URL
    ) {
        self.httpClient = httpClient
        self.url = loadURL
    }
    
    public enum Error : Swift.Error {
        case connectivity
        case invalidData
    }
    
    public func getExerciseList() -> AnyPublisher<[ExerciseItem], Swift.Error> {
        Future { [weak self] promise in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            self.httpClient.get(from: self.url) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success((let response, let data)):
                    promise(ExerciseListRemoteProvider.map(data, from: response))
                case .failure(_):
                    promise(.failure(Error.connectivity))
                }
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private static func map(_ data: Data, from response: HTTPURLResponse) -> Result<[ExerciseItem], Swift.Error> {
        do {
            let items = try ExerciseItemsMapper.map(data, from: response)
            return .success(items)
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Now each element of `[ExerciseItem]` has a `id` field and I need to make another call with this id which will be something like following:

```swift
public final class ExerciseInfoRemoteProvider: ExerciseInfoRemoteProviderProtocol {
    
    private let httpClient: HTTPClient
    private let url: URL
    
    public init(
        client httpClient: HTTPClient,
        url loadURL: URL
    ) {
        self.httpClient = httpClient
        self.url = loadURL
    }
    
    func getExerciseInfo(id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<ExerciseInfo, Error> {
        Future { [weak self] promise in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            self.httpClient.get(from: self.url) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success((let response, let data)):
                    promise(ExerciseListRemoteProvider.map(data, from: response))
                case .failure(_):
                    promise(.failure(Error.connectivity))
                }
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }    
}
```

How do I make above API request in loop from first API and receive data (mainly image)? I also want to show these images in UITableView asynchronously as I receive it.